# "Cool down" vs "getting cool"

Tags: causative-get

Just the other day, I wanted to say

> It's a good way to cool down.

But since nowadays, in modern speech we use "get" almost for everything, I said the following instead:

> It's a good way to get cool

and it sounded most probably wrong to me immediately. Or I'm mistaken?

Comment: I would understand these differently.  "To get cool" would mean I'm hot and I want to get cool (could also say, "to cool off").  "Cool down" sounds to me like what you do at the end of an exercise session; this is a specific kind of cooling yourself which has to do with letting the warmed-up muscles cool off with slow activity, as stopping intense exercise suddenly is not so good for the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are valid and mean pretty much the same thing. My totally subjective feeling is that "cool down" sounds better.

I don't know what you mean by "we use get almost for everything". Probably not a good rule.

Comment: We can probably use 'get' in casual speech for most situations where we might use 'become', but, as you imply, that is not 'everything' or even almost that.